# Execute a SQL agent job based off a constraint

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent, sql-agent-job

How do you execute a SQL server agent job in a schedule only if a certain criteria is met.
My example is that I only want to run the job if a boolean value on a different server is set to true otherwise it must not run

Comment: You will need to have a linked server to the server B, 'boolean value' server.  Check that value w/ TSQL and if true, use sp_start_job on server A.

Comment: Thank you and if i want to do it through a schedule?

Comment: On server A, you have the job you want to run.  Don't have that job run automatically.  You can create it and not schedule it.  What you want to do is create a new TSQL job that checks the value on server B, then executes sp_start_job on server A.

Comment: Alternately, you can have a scheduled task on server B that checks itself, then runs sp_start_job on server A through a linked server query.

Comment: This new job that runs sp_start_job is the one you want to schedule.

Comment: You could also create an SSIS package that has this logic, but that's really too complex for something this simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedules are not conditional.   They run at the time they are scheduled, no matter what.

If you want your job to do something only when certain conditions are met, you have to expect that the job will always run on schedule, and put something in the steps that the job executes to check the condition.

So if your job executes SQL Statements, you would put `IF` blocks in your SQL.   If it executes an SSIS package, you would start the package by checking a condition, and so on.

Comment: Thank You this is very helpful